# rspec before(:each) hook - conditionally apply

Tags: rspec, rspec-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I have following in my `rails_helper.rb`:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  # ...
  config.before(:each, type: :controller) do
    # SOMETHING
  end
end
```

I want to define directories, to which this `SOMETHING` will be applicable (in my case ONLY to files under `spec/controllers/api` directory).

Any chance to achieve that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a more specialized name for your [RSpec filter](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/hooks/filters):

```rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  # ...
  config.before(:each, subtype: :controllers_api) do
    # SOMETHING
  end
end
```

And then in your RSpec examples in `spec/controllers/api`, you add some metadata:

```rb
RSpec.describe "something", subtype: :controllers_api do
end
```

This `SOMETHING` will run only on examples having the `subtype: :controllers_api` metadata.

To automatically derive metadata from file location, use [`define_derived_metadata`](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/rspec/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/Configuration:define_derived_metadata) like so:

```rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  # Tag all groups and examples in the spec/controllers/api directory
  # with subtype: :controllers_api
  config.define_derived_metadata(file_path: %r{/spec/controllers/api}) do |metadata|
    metadata[:subtype] = :controllers_api
  end
end
```