# RSpec Variable Scoping

Tags: ruby, rspec, sinatra, sequel

I am having difficulties accessing the globally available `@db` variable within my rspec tests. The `@db` variable is set within the app which is included via the spec_helper.

Code below:

```
require File.expand_path '../../spec_helper.rb', __FILE__


p @db
describe MyModel do
  before do
    p @db
  end
  context 'constraints' do
    it 'is expected to do something' do
      p @db
    end
  end
end
```

When I run this, I get the output:

```
#<Sequel::Mysql2::Database: "mysql2://root:@localhost/my_project">
nil
nil
```

indicating that the `@db` variable is properly set from outside the rspec test, but is not accessible once the test runs. How can I access `@db` from within my test?

Answer (score 1):

Variables that start with an `@` sigil are *instance variables*. They belong to a particular *object* (i.e. instance), and can be accessed *only* from that object. They are always looked up relative to `self`.

In your case, you have *two different* instance variables of *two different* objects.

On line 4, `self` is the so-called `main` top-level object. On lines 7 and 11, `self` is an instance of the class `RSpec::ExampleGroups::MyModel::Constraints`, a totally different object of a totally different class with a totally different set of instance variables.

If you *really* need to access *that* particular instance variable, you could do something like this:

```
$main = self

require File.expand_path '../../spec_helper.rb', __FILE__


p @db
describe MyModel do
  before do
    p $main.instance_variable_get(:@db)
  end
  context 'constraints' do
    it 'is expected to do something' do
      p $main.instance_variable_get(:@db)
    end
  end
end
```

But the easiest solution would be to just set the instance variable on the *correct* object in the `before` hook.

Comment: The database object is being set via sinatra-sequel (https://github.com/rtomayko/sinatra-sequel/blob/master/lib/sinatra/sequel.rb). Any idea how to access the ```database``` object?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you have in your `spec_helper.rb`, but you should include this:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:each) do
    @db = 'your db object'
  end
end
```

This is the same as defining before hook directly above your test example, except it will run globally before each test.

Comment: You can also specify filters when setting global rules, see this thread for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29094646/rspec-beforeeach-hook-conditionally-apply

Comment: I tried that with no success. I still get a ```nil``` for ```@db```. I did @db = database with no success.